# JS: Prototyping - access the right instance property

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm a little confused about prototyping in JS. I've prepared a fiddle for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GBCav/7/

Markup:

```
<div class="container1">
    <p>Container 1</p>
    <button>Turn me (container1) red</button>
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <p>Container 2</p>
    <button>Turn me (container2) red</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Constructor Function
function Box( container ) {
  this.container = $(container);
}

// Prototype method
Box.prototype = {
  init : function() {

      // Assign buttons to object variable
      this.button = this.container.find('button');

      $this = this; // Set 'this' to Slider object
      this.button.on('click', function() {
        // It is getting the wrong container here, but why
        $this.container.css('background-color','red');
      });
  }
};
```

Here's how I call the constructor function:

```
// Create two instances of box
(function() {
    var container1 = new Box( $('div.container1') );
    container1.init();

    var container2 = new Box( $('div.container2') );
    container2.init();
})();
```

I have two Box-objects created by a constructor function. When I click on a button inside of a box, the background of the CONTAINING box should change the color.

The change of color is handled in the init prototype function of the Box.

However, the wrong box is getting colored with the code above. How do I address the right container?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `var` statement:

```
$this = this;
```

should be:

```
var $this = this;
```

Add in `var` and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/GBCav/8/

Explanation: When you omit the `var` keyword, you're assigning `$this` to a global variable, rather than one limited to the scope of the `.init()` method. The assignment happens when you call `.init()`, so calling this method on the second instance re-assigns `$this` to the second instance, affecting the value of `$this` in the first instance's event handler as well.